# $(element).is(':visible') is false always

Tags: jquery

I have the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/LAMdV/

HTML:

```
<div id="imageSlider">
    <span class="info" id="info1">
        hello world
    </span>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#imageSlider .info').click(function () {
    var i = $(this).attr('id');
    i = i.replace('info', '');

    if ($('#imageSliders .info#info' + i).is(':visible')) {    
        alert("hide");
    } else {
        alert("show");
    }
});
```

Why is the results of `is:visible` always showing false? Despite the fact it's visible from the start! (In my actual scenario it's previously hidden and then displayed)

Comment: @Ates Goral gave you the answer. However, there is no need to do `$('#imageSliders .info#info' + i)`, because IDs must be unique. So, it's much cleaner and faster to do `$('#info' + i)`, although you wouldn't need it, because `$(this)` is already the element you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you all, think Friday afternoon blues are setting in, can tell it's the end of a week! I'll mark it as an answer in a minute but unable to right now. Thanks for your other advice Shef :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your markup has id "imageSlider" while your selector uses "#imageSliders" (plural).

Answer (score 2):

It might be because the id is imageSlider and your jQuery has #imageSliders (plural).

Answer (score 1):

You have your syntax mixed up.

```
 if ($('#imageSliders .info#info' + i).is(':visible')) { ... }
```

class names are referenced after ids. However ids are the fastest selector so just get the info{number} as the primary selector

```
 if ($('#info' + i).is(':visible')) { ... }
```

However since this is in a function call you can just use `this`

```
 if ($(this).is(':visible')) { ... }
```

To further explain when you would used class combined with an id. Take an example of an id on a page that could be decorated with the class active.

```
$("#uniqueid")
```

vs

```
$("#uniqueid.active")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is neither of them. imageSliders should be imageSlider